# How to display textarea for review?

Tags: jquery

I have problem to display the value of textarea on keyup inside a p tag. My problem is when I press enter key, the preview-value doesn't create a new line. I try something like e.keycode == 13 but it doesn't work as well.
My current code is:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/bsvjhj1n/2/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<p>` elements treat all whitespace (spaces, tabs, new lines, etc.) as a single space. Depending on your use case you might want to use a `<pre>` tag instead, as in this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/pthr96x4/3/

Alternatively you could replace new line characters with `<br>` tags as in this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/yvmbenbz/2/
Note that `.html()` is used instead of `.text()`.